# Apache Camel Spring Boot Java - how can I pass a dynamic value from a rest route to a from file route?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, java-11

I have an Apache Camel [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) route. I want to call this REST post route from [Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postman/info), and I want to send it JSON content that contains a file path. Then I want to read that file path to use it in a route a `from file route`.

So far I have this:

```
@Component
    class RestApi extends RouteBuilder {
        @Override
        public void configure() {
            CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

            restConfiguration()
                    .contextPath(contextPath)
                    .port(serverPort)
                    .enableCORS(true)
                    .apiContextPath("/api-doc")
                    .apiProperty("api.title", "Test REST API")
                    .apiProperty("api.version", "v1")
                    .apiContextRouteId("doc-api")
                    .component("servlet")
                    .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json);
            rest("/api/")
                    .id("api-route")
                    .consumes("application/json")
                    .post("/bean")
                    .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json_xml)
                    .type(MyBean.class)
                    .to("direct:remoteService");
            from("direct:remoteService")
                    .routeId("direct-route")
                    .tracing()
                    .log(">>> ${body.id}")
                    .log(">>> ${body.name}")

                    // I tried calling it with "toD"
```

But it is not working.

```
                    .toD("file://${body.name}?fileName=sources.zip&noop=true&delay=5000&moveFailed=error");
            from("file://${body.name}?fileName=sources.zip&noop=true&delay=5000&moveFailed=error")
                    .tracing()
                    .log(">>> ${body.id}")
                    .log(">>> ${body.name}")
                    .log("Loading zip file ${file:name}")
                    .split(new ZipSplitter())
                    .streaming()
                    .to("direct:another-route");
        }
    }
```

I tried using toD, but I get the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid directory: ${body.name}. Dynamic expressions with ${ } placeholders is not allowed. Use the fileName option to set the dynamic expression.

I want to get that path that is send with Postman `body.name`. I can get that value, because it is showing in the logs and then use that path to start the *from* file path route,

```
from("file://${body.name}?fileName=sources.zip&noop=true&delay=5000&moveFailed=error")
                    .tracing()
                    .log(">>> ${body.id}")
                    .log(">>> ${body.name}")
                    .log("Loading zip file ${file:name}")
                    .split(new ZipSplitter())
                    .streaming()
                    .to("direct:another-route");
```

**EDIT**

I tried using pollEncrich, but I need to pass a variable, the one that I get from the post route `${body.name}`. How can I pass that variable to the route of the pollEnrich?

I tried with this, but it isn't working:

```
rest("/api/")
                    .id("api-route")
                    .consumes("application/json")
                    .post("/bean")
                    .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json_xml)
                    .type(MyBean.class)
                    .to("direct:remoteService");
            from("direct:remoteService")
                    .routeId("direct-route")
                    .tracing()
                    .log(">>> ${body.id}")
                    .log(">>> ${body.name}")
                    .pollEnrich("file://${body.name}?fileName=sources.zip&noop=true&delay=5000&moveFailed=error")
                    .split(new ZipSplitter())
                    .streaming()
                    .to("direct:process-files");
```

I get the following error:

> Invalid directory: ${body.name}. Dynamic expressions with ${ } placeholders is not allowed. Use the fileName option to set the dynamic expression.

Answer (score 0):

See the content enricher EIP (to and toD on a file is to write as a new file). You need to use pollEnrich (content enricher) to load the existing file.

Comment: thanks, I treid with pollEnrich but I get the following error `Invalid directory: ${body.name}. Dynamic expressions with ${ } placeholders is not allowed. Use the fileName option to set the dynamic expression.` I need to pass a variable to to that route, I tried using ${body.name} but isnt working